# Laravel reverse search of records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm having a hard time trying to get an approach to my problem.

I have two tables. One for companies and another one for services provided by every company. Every service have a foreign key 'id_company' that reference him to a provider company. So my model is like this.

```
TABLE COMPANIES.

id_company        INTEGER,
NAME              VARCHAR,
blah, blah

TABLE SERVICES.
id_service        INTEGER,
id_company        INTEGER,
type_of_service   INTEGER,
name              VARCHAR,
blah, blah.
```

My Eloquent model is like.

```
class company {
   public function services() {
      return $this->hasMany('Service', 'id_service');
   }
}

class service {
   public function company() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Company');
   }
}
```

I need to list all companies that offer a service. SQL should look like

```
SELECT id_company FROM companies as c
                  JOIN services as s ON s.id_company = c.id_company
                  WHERE s.type_of_service = a_number.
```

I know about Eloquent basis but I can't get to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you all companies that offer 1 or more services. (Any company that **has** a service)

```
$companies = Company::has('services')->get();
```

[Docs Eloquent Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

**Update**

Your answer is correct. I had read your question wrong. You can use the `whereHas` method if you want to find companies that have a service meeting your criteria.

```
$companies = Company::whereHas('services', function ($q) use ($a_number)
{
    $q->where('type_of_service', $a_number);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself.

```
$companies = Company::whereHas('services', function($q) {
   $q->where('id_service', a_number);
})->get()
```

Thank, anyway for the response.